# SCSS problem with @use Error: Invalid CSS after "

Tags: css, import, sass

Hi I have a question about SCSS. When I work with `@use` I get this Error:

`Invalid CSS after "... mily: variables": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ". $ FontSansPro;"`

My:

_variables.scss

```
$fontSansPro: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
```

style.scss

```
@use './variables/variables';

body {
    font-family: variables.$fontSansPro;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Dart Sass?

Comment: yes i am, does that mean i can't use it?

Comment: Hum no, it should work... `@use` is only available with Dart Sass.